# How to display LAS file on ForgeViewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, point-clouds, las

I'm looking for a way to display LAS files on ForgeViewer.

Currently I can extract points for display using THREE.PointCloudMaterial. but the extraction is quite slow and I would like to know more possible methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a couple ways...

**First option:**

> Convert the LAS files to Potree and use the potree extension in forge-viewer, like this:
> https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-potree-demo

**Second option:**

> Load the LAS files in Recap Pro and save the RCP/RCS files to BIM360/ACC.  From there, use the 3D-Tiles extension to load them into Forge Viewer, like this example:
> https://github.com/wallabyway/hub-browser-recap-ext

[image]